# Getting current location in React for mapbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox

I'm new to React and Mapbox. I found Mapbox is smoother than google map and would like to use it in my web app. I would like set the default location to the current location. This is how my workaround but is there a better way to get the current location for my map?

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import ReactMapGL, { Marker, Popup } from "react-map-gl";

const MAPBOX_TOKEN = "TOKEN";

function App() {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 45.4211,
    longitude: -75.6903,
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh",
    zoom: 10,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
      setViewport({
        ...viewport,
        latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
        longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <ReactMapGL
        {...viewport}
        mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      ></ReactMapGL>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: react-map-gl has GeolocateControl https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/geolocate-control

Comment: Is that possible that I can use initialViewState={viewport} to set the current location as well? I would like to have more control rather than using some api.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid rendering the map until you have the view port:

```
const [viewPort, setViewPort] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
      setViewport({
        width: "100vw",
        height: "100vh",
        zoom: 10,
        latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
        longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
      });
    });
}, []);

return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      {viewPort ? <ReactMapGL
        {...viewport}
        mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      ></ReactMapGL> : null}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I am using typescript so using undefined doesn't work. Any workaround? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you denied access to geolocation, is this the case?